# Filter library code from /analyze results

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-code-analysis

I'm trying to use C++ Visual Studio `/analyze` to do static code analysis on my project.
The main issue I'm having with it is that the vast majority of warnings I get are from various libraries I'm including like boost and protobuf and not from my code.
Is there a way to filter out the warnings by path? (other than copying to a text file and doing grep...)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/zyhb0b82(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), I suggest that you could try this method.

- To enable or disable a code analysis warning

1.Create a header file that lists all the code analysis warnings and their initial state, as shown in the following code:

```
// WarningState.h
   #pragma warning ( default : 6001 )
   #pragma warning ( disable : 6011 )
// more warnings here 
// end of file
```

2.Include WarningState.h in the application header file. In this case, MyApplication.h represents the header file.

```
// MyApplication.h file
   #include "WarningState.h"
// ...
// end of file
```

3.Include MyApplication.h file in the source code file. In this case, MyApplication.cpp represents the source file.

```
// MyApplication.cpp file
#include "MyApplication.h"
```

4.To modify the warning state, use the pragma warning-specifier in a .cpp file, as shown in the following code:

```
// MyApplication.cpp file
#include "MyApplication.h"
#pragma warning ( disable: 6001 )
#pragma warning ( default : 6001 )
```

- To disable all code analysis warnings for included third-party files

Add the following code to your header file.

```
#include <codeanalysis\warnings.h>
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning ( disable : ALL_CODE_ANALYSIS_WARNINGS )
#include <third-party include files here>
#pragma warning( pop )
```

Comment: That is truly an awful solution. Usage of code analysis solutions should not depend on changes to the code to make them work properly

Comment: To be honest, I think that copying to a text file and doing grep is a better method.